# HyperGraphQL- Federating the SPARQL across multiple services

Tags: graphql, sparql, ontology

I am not sure if its the way I am using `HyperGraphQL` or my limited knowledge of SPARQL/RDF, any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to setup multiple SPARQL endpoints and want to be able to create a graph that is able to span across these endpoint.

I have tried to use the following `chinook.db` and I have split this data in to 3 different SPARQL services like shown below:
[image]

I am trying to create a SPARQL link across these service boundaries, for e.g. `customers` object in `Orders` service has a link to a `employees` object in `HR` service so that when I query for `Customer` I am able to get `(Orders)Customer.SupportedRep --> (HR)Employee`. basically I should be able to get Employee details supporting that customer.

I have setup my configuration like below:

***1. chinook.json***

```
{
    "name": "chinook-hgql",
    "schema": "chinook.graphql",
    "server": {
        "port": 8889,
        "graphql": "/graphql",
        "graphiql": "/graphiql"
    },
    "services": [
       {
            "id": "chinook-orders-sparql",
            "type": "LocalModelSPARQLService",
            "filepath": "chinook/chinook-orders.ttl",
            "filetype": "TTL"
        },
        {
            "id": "chinook-hr-sparql",
            "type": "SPARQLEndpointService",
            "url": "http://localhost:7003/sparql",
            "graph": "",
            "user": "",
            "password": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

***2: Schema File: chinook.graphql***

```
type __Context {
    Customers: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS")


    Employees: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES")

    label:   _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label")
    comment: _@href(iri: "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment")

    customerId: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_CUSTOMERID")
    customerFirstName: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_FIRSTNAME")
    customerLastName: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_LASTNAME")
    customerCompany: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_COMPANY")
    customerAddress: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_ADDRESS")
    customerCity: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_CITY")
    customerState: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_STATE")
    customerCountry: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_COUNTRY")
    customerPostalCode: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_POSTALCODE")
    customerPhone: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_PHONE")
    customerFax: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_FAX")
    customerEmail: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_EMAIL")
    SupportRep: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_SUPPORTREPID")


  employeeId: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_EMPLOYEEID")
  employeeFirstName: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_FIRSTNAME")
  employeeLastName: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_LASTNAME")
  employeeTitle: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_TITLE")
  employeeReportsTo: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_REPORTSTO")
  employeeBirthDate: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_BIRTHDATE")
  employeeHireDate: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_HIREDATE")
  employeeAddress: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_ADDRESS")
  employeeCity: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_CITY")
  employeeState: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_STATE")
  employeeCountry: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_COUNTRY")
  employeePostalCode: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_POSTALCODE")
  employeePhone: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_PHONE")
  employeeFax: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_FAX")  
  employeeEmail: _@href(iri: "http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_EMAIL")

}

type Customers @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql") {
  customerId: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerFirstName: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerLastName: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerCompany: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerAddress: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerCity: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerState: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerCountry: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerPostalCode: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerPhone: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerFax: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  customerEmail: String @service(id:"chinook-orders-sparql")
  SupportRep: Employees @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
}


type Employees @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql") {
  employeeId: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeFirstName: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeLastName: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeTitle: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeReportsTo: Employees @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeBirthDate: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeHireDate: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeAddress: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeCity: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeState: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeCountry: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeePostalCode: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeePhone: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")
  employeeFax: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")  
  employeeEmail: String @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql") 
}
```

Please notice how I am trying to build this relationship above, and this is where I am having issues:

***SupportRep: Employees @service(id:"chinook-hr-sparql")***

ALSO in my data in the TTL file I have changes the links for SupportRep to have the links to the URI of HR system by manually editing the values to show the following:

```
<http://localhost:7002/resource/CUSTOMERS/1> rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                                                      vocab:CUSTOMERS ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_ADDRESS "Av. Brigadeiro Faria Lima, 2170" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_CITY "São José dos Campos" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_COMPANY "Embraer - Empresa Brasileira de Aeronáutica S.A." ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_COUNTRY "Brazil" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_CUSTOMERID 1 ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_EMAIL "luisg@embraer.com.br" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_FAX "+55 (12) 3923-5566" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_FIRSTNAME "Luís" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_LASTNAME "Gonçalves" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_PHONE "+55 (12) 3923-5555" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_POSTALCODE "12227-000" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_STATE "SP" ;
                                             vocab:CUSTOMERS_SUPPORTREPID <http://localhost:7003/resource/EMPLOYEES/3> ;
                                             rdfs:label "CUSTOMERS #1" .
```

Please notice the `vocab:CUSTOMERS_SUPPORTREPID <http://localhost:7003/resource/EMPLOYEES/3>` how it points to an outside URL on `port 7003` instead of `7002`

When I try to fetch the Customer's SupportRep Name, the query is failing on the `HyperGraphQL` with following message:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: HttpException: 400 HTTP 400 error making the query:
 Parse error:  SELECT  * WHERE   { VALUES ?x_2 { <http://localhost:7002/resource/CUSTOMERS/11> }     OPTIONAL       { ?x_2    <http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_SUPPORTREPID>  ?x_2_1 .         ?x_2_1  a                     <http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES>         OPTIONAL           { ?x_2_1  <http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_FIRSTNAME>  ?x_2_1_1 }       }   }   
Lexical error at line 3, column 11.  Encountered: " " (32), after : "VALUES"
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
            at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.services.SPARQLEndpointService.iterateFutureResults(SPARQLEndpointService.java:86)
            at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.services.SPARQLEndpointService.executeQuery(SPARQLEndpointService.java:69)
            at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.ExecutionTreeNode.generateTreeModel(ExecutionTreeNode.java:357)
            at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.FetchingExecution.call(FetchingExecution.java:21)
            at org.hypergraphql.datafetching.FetchingExecution.call(FetchingExecution.java:8)]
```

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong with my approach, or how can I fix this issue?

***UPDATE 1:***

I finally managed to get the logging working and here is what I see on the logs:

```
[pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.hypergraphql.datafetching.SPARQLEndpointExecution  - SELECT * WHERE { VALUES ?x_1 { <http://localhost:7002/resource/CUSTOMERS/11> }  OPTIONAL { ?x_1 <http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_SUPPORTREPID> ?x_1_1 .?x_1_1 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES> . OPTIONAL { ?x_1_1 <http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_FIRSTNAME> ?x_1_1_1 . }  }  } 
[pool-5-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp  - [1] GET http://localhost:7003/sparql?query=SELECT++*%0AWHERE%0A++%7B+VALUES+%3Fx_1+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7002%2Fresource%2FCUSTOMERS%2F11%3E+%7D%0A++++OPTIONAL%0A++++++%7B+%3Fx_1++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7002%2Fresource%2Fvocab%2FCUSTOMERS_SUPPORTREPID%3E++%3Fx_1_1+.%0A++++++++%3Fx_1_1++a+++++++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7003%2Fresource%2Fvocab%2FEMPLOYEES%3E%0A++++++++OPTIONAL%0A++++++++++%7B+%3Fx_1_1++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7003%2Fresource%2Fvocab%2FEMPLOYEES_FIRSTNAME%3E++%3Fx_1_1_1+%7D%0A++++++%7D%0A++%7D%0A
```

So, its actually making the call to the external `SPARQL endpoint` however the endpoint at `http://localhost:7003/sparql` knows nothing about

`{ VALUES ?x_1 { <http://localhost:7002/resource/CUSTOMERS/11> }`

how can we address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out that the way `HyperGraphQL` generates these `SPARQL` is like below

```
SELECT * WHERE { VALUES ?x_1 { <http://localhost:7002/resource/CUSTOMERS/11> }  OPTIONAL { ?x_1 <http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_SUPPORTREPID> ?x_1_1 .?x_1_1 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES> . OPTIONAL { ?x_1_1 <http://localhost:7003/resource/vocab/EMPLOYEES_FIRSTNAME> ?x_1_1_1 . }  }  }
```

and this is actually sent on

`http://localhost:7003/sparql?query=`

so its basically expecting that there is a graph available on `7003` that contains the customers like this `<http://localhost:7002/resource/CUSTOMERS/11>` and `?x_1 <http://localhost:7002/resource/vocab/CUSTOMERS_SUPPORTREPID> ?x_1_1 .`

I got it working by copying the customer master data and this relationship over to my `HR SYS` on `7003` from `Orders SYS` on `7002` then this is working just fine.

However I think this breaks the very purpose of `SPARQL` federation.